# Business rules application to design encompasses... - help me make sense of that phrase

Tags: meaning, grammar

> This chapter is the final of four chapters covering the case study design of the relational database model for the online auction house company. **Business rules application to design encompasses** stored procedures, as well as specialized and very detailed field formatting and restrictions.

I can't make sense of the part that's in bold.

Comment: That is a very [ambiguous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rules_engine) sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess

> [(The) {Business-rules application} to design] encompasses [stored procedures, as well as specialized and very detailed field formatting and restrictions].

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that this is a typo and they're missing an 'and' or 'and their' after 'Business rules.'

You'd then have

**'Business rules and their application to [database] design encompasses stored procedures, as well as specialized and very detailed formatting and restrictions.'**

In my limited knowledge of databasing this makes sense. You can use the features of an RDBMS, like your stored procedures and field formatting, to fit the business logic your client might want applied to their data.

No comment as to whether I'd think that is well written, even with the typo correction.